# Angular app cannot launch in Docker with missing angular-devkit package.json

Tags: angular, docker

I try to make container with my angular app. When I clone it from Github without node_modules it throws an error:

> frontend          | An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find
> module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json' frontend
> | Require stack: frontend          | -
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js frontend          | -
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
> frontend          | -
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
> frontend          | -
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
> frontend          | -
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
> frontend          | -
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
> frontend          | -
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
> frontend          | -
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
> frontend          | -
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js frontend
> | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js frontend
> | - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng frontend
> | See "/tmp/ng-7mb3NX/angular-errors.log" for further details.
> frontend exited with code 127

Angular dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14  
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./  
RUN npm install  RUN npm install -g @angular/cli  
COPY . /usr/src/app  
EXPOSE 4200  
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "plant-expert",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.25",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your package.json file?

Comment: @JohnGraham as You aksked I added package.json content.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to recreate this and my container runs fine. Although I did have to move the angular cli RUN to its own line from your sample dockerfile. One thing to maybe try is either to install an explicit cli version in your docker build like `npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.19` to match your repo or you could not worry about the global CLI and change your cmd and package script to be `CMD npm start ` and `"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0",`